# Unable to render prompt in this FizzBuzz code?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and have been working on this FizzBuzz problem for a couple of days. Although I feel like I understand how to solve FizzBuzz, I am not able to render the prompt when the page loads. 
I'm basically trying to take the number that the user inputs into the prompt and run a for loop over it but after I write the for loop and conditional statements the prompt stops popping up when the page is reloaded. 
I feel silly since this seems to be a problem with a simple solution and I've searched but I haven't found anything similar to this problem. I'll include my jsfiddle. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/eh_sisyphus/bxqhuktk/5/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    function FizzBuzz() {

      var myPrompt = parseInt(prompt("What number would you like?"),   0);

      for (var i = 0; i<=myPrompt; i++) {

          if (i%3 === 0) {

             return "Fizz";

          } else if (i%5 === 0) {

            return "Buzz";

          } else (i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0){

            return i;

          }
       }  
     }
    });
```

Comment: Do you invoke your `FizzBuzz` function? Btw, have you checked the JS console? There is at least one syntax error there.

Comment: What are you passing base `0` to `parseInt()`?

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? If you don't know how to debug JavaScript: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Your program won't be printing FizzBuzz for numbers divisble by 3 *and* 5....

Answer (score 2):

here's the solution:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxqhuktk/8/)

#### js

```
function FizzBuzz() {

    var myPrompt = parseInt(prompt("What number would you like?"));

    for (var i = 0; i <= myPrompt; i++) {

        if (i % 3 === 0) {

             console.log("Fizz");

        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {

            console.log("Buzz");

        } else if ((i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 != 0)) {

            console.log(i);

        }
    }

}


$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log(FizzBuzz());

});
```

#### Explanation

you had several mistakes:

1. Didn't include jQuery: you're using a 3rd party library called jQuery in order to trigger the "onDOMContentLoaded" event - $(document).ready
2. didn't call the function - you've declared it but never used it
3. forgot an 'if' on your last else statement
4. passed '0' to parseInt meaning it will cast your input into base 0 (zero to zero)
5. used return within the loop - the return will immediately exit the function so the loop will only have a single iteration.

You'll see your output in the console (F12 -> console) on windows or cmd+alt+i -> console on mac

Comment: This is still contains the bug from OPs solution. This won't print FizzBuzz for numbers divisible by 3 *and* 5.

Comment: I haven't added it since it's a design flaw rather than a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement takes no parameters and is written simply as `else { ... }`. You will want to use an `else if` other than `else` here:

```
} else (i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0){
```

Should be:

```
} else if (i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0){
```

Along with that you need to execute the function `FizzBuzz()`:

```
function FizzBuzz() {
    ...
}
FizzBuzz();
```

Since you a returning something, you may want to do:

```
console.log(FizzBuzz());
```

To see what value was returned from `FizzBuzz()`.

*Note:* This will fix your problem with the function running and the `prompt` showing. Although, your solution does not solve the *FizzBuzz* problem. Mainly because you are looping from `0 to n`, once you hit the first `if` as true `Fizz` will be returned and the function will exit. You will never get `Buzz` or `FizzBuzz`. Instead of doing `return`, print out the value using `console.log()`.

Finally to go with your deign, to get `"FizzBuzz"` you can check `if(i%15 === 0)` as the first condition, the rest being `else if`:

```
   for (var i = 0; i<=myPrompt; i++) {

        if(i%15 === 0) {

            console.log("FizzBuzz");

        } else if (i%3 === 0) {

            console.log("Fizz");

        } else if (i%5 === 0) {

            console.log("Buzz");

        } else if(i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0){ // Note you can change this to just "else".

            console.log(i);

        }
  }
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxqhuktk/9/)

Comment: This will not work since the loop contains multiple returns that will exit the function upon the first iteration.
I've addressed it as well in my solution.

Comment: @Mike86 I specifically mentioned that in my original solution *"... once you hit the first if as true Fizz will be returned and the function will exit. Instead of doing return, print out the value using console.log()"*. The user asked why the prompt isn't showing, and I gave an answer. Then explained why their solution to FizzBuzz does not work.

Comment: Sorry, i've missed that out